# Мгновенные уведомления пользователям

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, php, runtime

Задача стоит в мгновенном уведомлении пользователям о новых записях в таблице.
Пользователь подписываться на категории (статьи, новости) и при появлении новых записей в этих категориях необходимо послать юзеру уведомление в личном кабинете.
Какие технологии применить? Как это обычно делается?

Comment: как вы и указали в тегах темы, Ajax - то что вам нужно. Документацию можно найти в гугле. и тут момент, мгновенно это "сколько вешать в граммах"? для меня это меньше секунды, для вас может быть меньше 10 сек, или меньше 10 мин?) ставите js функцию которая будет проверять на сервере новые данные раз в нужное время, и радуетесь.

Comment: @ToRcH565, 
плохая затея, тут нужно использовать Comet
Зачем лишний раз тревожить сервер, ладно вы один, а когда таких как вы 1000? если сервер слабенький то ляжет очень быстро

Answer (score 4):

Начните свои изыскания отсюда: [Comet](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(программирование))

Comment: Да-да, погуглите на тему long polling и использование для этого nginx.

Возможно решением вашего вопроса окажется [WebSockets][1]. Его легче всего сделать на NodeJS, но для php тоже есть ["костыль"][2]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket
  [2]: https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Answer (score 0):

Создайте SQL таблицу с полями topic и user, и добавляйте туда свои новости, а когда пользователь заходит в свой кабинет, делайте выборку из этой таблицы WHERE user=$user

Comment: Как запасной вариант. может и сойдет

Comment: я вас как-то не понимаю. в смысле как запасной? а иначе где вы сообщения хранить будете? а способ доставки - ajax, или обычное обновление не так важен.